# NSOrderedSet for object pointers only

Tags: objective-c

I need to store a bunch of objects in an `NSOrderedSet` object.

Unfortunately, I don't want the set to perform any sort of equality checking on anything other than the object pointer itself.

It appears as though some objects (such as `NSNumber`) override `isEqual:` and perform internal value comparison, which means that two `NSNumber` instances with the same value (but different object pointers) cannot be stored in the same ordered set.

How can I work around this issue?

It has occurred to me that I could just store the object pointer itself as an `NSValue` or `NSString` object (using `@"%p"`) instead.

However this means that I need to wrap all calls to `containsObject:` and `indexOfObject:` and create a new `NSValue` or `NSString` object every time I want to query the set.

Is there any better way of handling this?

Comment: Could you wrap everything you put into the NSOrderedSet in a wrapper class? It could implement `isEqual` to perform identity checking on its wrapped object. And the wrapped object can be easily extracted, obviously.

Comment: See if NSMapTable gets close to what you want.

Comment: @JoshCaswell It isn't ordered. I do not remember that there is an unmanaged replacement for NSOrderedSet.

Comment: Do you need the set functionality or can you use an array?